# Simulating enzymatic change rates of Carbonic anhydrase

Tags: physical-chemistry, biochemistry, computational-chemistry

I'm trying to simulate effects of carbonic anhydrase on cellular pH as caused by changes in bicarbonate. I assume a bicarbonate homeostatic mechanisms which replenishes intracellular concentrations from

$$\ce{CO2 + H2O <=> H+ + HCO3- }$$

One paper I’ve found states the assumptions and rates, but doesn’t parameterize the differential (difference) relation between the substrates and products. The paper merely states that given the time scales I’m considering, it’s ok to assume $p(\ce{CO2})$ is constant, since carbon dioxide’s diffusion is fast in aqueous media. Secondly, the article states that

> The equilibrium constant of the reaction was $10^{-6.35}\ \mathrm{M}$ and the rate constant for $\ce{CO2}$ hydration was $10^6\ \mathrm{s^{-1}}$.

How do should I think of this reaction, and more importantly how do I simulate it?